# Validate Authentication on every request in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to check if the backend is returning a error code `ERR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED' whenever any fetch request is sent, and logout the user from frontend if this occurs.

Basically I want to redirect user to login whenever the token is incorrect, expired, etc. One method is polling, I poll the server every x seconds and validate, but the time between polls is vulnerable and the user may see lots of errors.

P.S. I'm a newbie to React, I work mostly on Django, what I would prefer is something like `@login_required` decorator in Django.

Comment: You have to protect the routes. To do that you have to have a global state of isAuthenticated. If the global isAuthenticated state is false you can redirect to the login page. If you're using react-router check how to protect routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in two ways:

1. Every fetch would attach the authentication token in the fetch's header, and the backend would check if the token is valid. If not, the backend would send a 301 Redirect response to your fetch pointing to your login page
2. You can handle this in the frontend by wrapping all your fetch request routes in a method that, if the fetch fails with Unauthorised, would redirect the page to login

Comment: The second one seems to be the solution I'm looking for, can you share a dummy code how to do "wrap"?

Comment: I'm going to illustrate for ExpressJS as the backend framework:

`function isTokenValid(token) { /* check if token valid */ }`

`function loginRequired(request, response, next) { if(!isTokenValid(request.header('Autorization'))) {response.redirect(301, /*redirection url*/)} /* else go about your business */ next()}`

`const app = express(); app.use(loginRequired);`

Comment: Thanks. That will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `response.status` on the back-end. It usually returns 401: not authorised.